# How to eliminate same docs to es index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Imagine that I have some docs and I am putting them on an elasticsearch index with the below python code;

```
es.index(index=index_name, doc_type='_doc', body=doc)
```

If i run the code twice, same 2 docs will be on this elasticsearch index.
How can i eliminate this duplication docs on same index ?
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the *?op_type=create* parameter to index a document only if no document with that ID exists. For example:

**Request 1**

```
PUT /customers/_doc/1?op_type=create
{
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

**Response 1**

```
{
  "_index" : "customers",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 0,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

**Request 2**

```
PUT /customers/_doc/1?op_type=create
{
  "name": "Jane Doe"
}
```

**Response 2**

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason" : "[1]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [1])",
        "index_uuid" : "5Oar4GFhQjq_EM88qqd6PA",
        "shard" : "0",
        "index" : "customers"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "version_conflict_engine_exception",
    "reason" : "[1]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [1])",
    "index_uuid" : "5Oar4GFhQjq_EM88qqd6PA",
    "shard" : "0",
    "index" : "customers"
  },
  "status" : 409
}
```

Comment: Yes thats the answer except one thing, how to set "?op_type=create" this in python ?

Comment: Inside of this "es.index(index=index_name, doc_type='_doc', body=doc)" ?

Comment: es.index(index="index_name", id=1, op_type='create', body=doc)

Comment: You made a good answer, if you liked the question feel free to upvote :)